# How to Logout facebook and delete cookies

Tags: ios

I am using latest facebook SDK,I need to pop to root viewcontroller after successfully logout but when i login again its not actually logout from facebook.I need to delete cookies or need to do something else here is my code

in `.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Logout"
                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(logoutButtonWasPressed:)];

   [super viewDidLoad];

 }

 -(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender
  {

    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete cookie from `UIWebView` you may try this:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://login.facebook.com"]];
        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
```

The cookie is saved in `NSUserDefaults` you can also clear cookie by clearing `NSUserDefault` data.

**EDIT:**

If you want to clear the cookie of safari from app then here is the answer:

"Mobile Safari's cookies are not accessible from SDK apps. And each SDK app is given its own WebKit cache and cookie stores, so while cookies will persist within the same app, they aren't accessible between apps".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are wanting is the initial flow of Facebook popping up and asking for permission to do stuff etc...

This is not achieved by logging out.

You can only do this by logging in to FaceBook and going into App Settings and removing permissions from there.

Comment: yes am using Facebook popping up and asking for permission,can you please explain more >You can only do this by logging in to FaceBook and going into App Settings and removing permissions from there.

Comment: Logging out of the app and removing cookies only does this from your phone. Facebook still stores the permissions on their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You log out using the `closeAndClearTokenInformation` method. If user used Safari to login with Facebook it may indeed keep the session cached. You can try removing the cookies in your logout method:

```
-(void)logoutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // Clear the cookies.
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) 
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: its not working,I need to show login popup each time when  user logout but still not any luck..